# Forcing area calculation into miles in QGIS (without changing the PCS)

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, geometry, area

I'm working on an assignment that requires me to create an area column in miles without changing the projected coordinate system. ArcGIS has a tool that can do this ('Calculate Geometry')-- does QGIS have anything analogous? I know about using $area in the Field Calculator but I cannot tell what units the resulting answers are in.

Comment: Please read my question closer. All the answers that I have found required me to change my projected coordinate system which I am unable to do. Do you know of an answer that does not require me to do so?

Comment: In any case, you wouldn't have to change the project CRS, since the field calculator $area always uses layer CRS units.

Comment: But I'm trying to force my field calculator $area into miles instead of the CRS units. ArcGIS has a function for this and I am hoping that someone can point me to the similar function in QGIS.

Comment: This is answered in the linked question. I guess you issue is not with converting between feet and miles ...

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't think that my question is answered. When I follow the instructions in the linked topic all I get is the same results as using $area. I don't know Python, though, so I may be missing something obvious...